# How to avoid duplicate code inside constructors? Java

Tags: java, constructor, code-duplication

Often when writing objects, I end up creating rather lengthy constructors or constructors containing code that is already present in the object's instance methods (duplicate code). I know that I can invoke these instance methods in the constructors, but I also understand that it is bad practice to. It's unsafe. How can I avoid duplicate code in my constructors while at the same time keeping my constructors safe?

At the moment, I'm replicating the card game Scopa. In my game object's constructor, I was initializing all instance variables, populating the deck, dealing cards to the players, and dealing cards to the table. I did all this so that the game would be in a state where it would be ready to play immediately after instantiation. However, a lot of this logic is duplicated as I stated before. For example, I have an instance method that deal cards to the players as well (for the case when I have to deal new cards).

After reading different sources, I resolved that the following code is a better way of doing it. Although, I'm still not happy with it... Basically it guarantees that every time someone wants to instantiate a new game that they have to call three instance methods for it to be in the playable, initial state.

```
public ScopaGame(
    final String playerName,
    final String computerName)
{
    deck = new Deck(); // creates an empty deck
    pile = new ArrayList<>();
    player = new Player(playerName);
    computer = new Player(computerName);
}
```

```
final ScopaGame game = new ScopaGame("Player 1", "Player 2");
game.refreshDeck(); // resets and shuffles the deck
game.dealToPlayers();
game.dealToTable();
```

Is avoiding the usage of constructors the best solution here? Such as in the following code? Here I created a instance method that instantiates and initializes the object. With this I could just make the constructor private and force the caller to use this method.

```
public static ScopaGame createGame(
    final String playerName,
    final String computerName)
{
    final ScopaGame game = new ScopaGame("Player 1", "Player 2");
    
    game.refreshDeck();
    game.dealToPlayers();
    game.dealToTable();
    
    return game;
}
```

Thank you, hopefully this made sense. Insight is highly appreciated. Please offer solutions with constructors that are instance method free and constructors that do not implement duplicate code.

Comment: "*I know that I can invoke these instance methods in the constructors, but I also understand that it is bad practice to. It's unsafe.*" - That is not necessarily true. It is unsafe if: - we leak a premature object or - the method we call is neither `private` nor `final`.

Comment: (Calling a `static` method may be OK too.)

Comment: I usually like to put this kind of initialization of the object in a private method called "init()" which I invoke in the constructor and whenever I wish the reinitializa the object. However I wouldn't put the three methods you invoke in there, I also think they shouldn't be aprt of the constrctor as they seem specific to the game itself

Comment: @Turing85 Ya, I've read about that. As a general rule though, I'd like to avoid having instance methods in the constructor. I've read that it is not great in general to have "business logic" in the constructor. What does this mean?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- I have seen heavy computations that were started through a constructor call. That's what meant with this statement. The constructor should do what it needs to do. Nothing less, nothing more. Have you considered to use factory methods?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that. I've had a hard time grasping what factory methods are.